# How can I make the plane receive shadows?

Tags: javascript, three.js

[I'm tying to get the plane to receive shadow from the sphere, but somewhere on my way I do something wrong, anyone that has an idea about how to fix it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk4ed.jpg)

```
//.................SETUP................//
import {
    WebGLRenderer,
    PerspectiveCamera,
    Scene,
    BoxGeometry,
    MeshBasicMaterial,
    Mesh,
    Group,
    PlaneGeometry,
    AxesHelper,
    GridHelper,
    DoubleSide,
    DirectionalLight,
    AmbientLight,
    MeshStandardMaterial,
    DirectionalLightHelper,
    Fog,
    TextureLoader,
    CubeTextureLoader,
    SphereGeometry,
} from './three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from './q.js';
//................PROGRAM...............//
var renderer, camera, scene, light, light1, geometry, material, mesh;
// renderer
renderer = new WebGLRenderer({canvas:
document.getElementById('Canvas'), antialias: true, alfa: true});
  //alfa: true gör att tomma pixlar i canvasen visar underliggande html-innehåll så att om man exempelvis skulle ha en bild under ett tomt canvas-element så kan man ändå se bilden. 
renderer.setClearColor(0x555555);
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.shadowMap.enable = true; 
// camera
camera = new PerspectiveCamera(35, window.innerWidth / 
window.innerHeight, 0.1, 6000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
//controls
var orbitcontrol = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement)
//scene
scene = new Scene();
//lights
//var ambientlight = new AmbientLight(0x333333);
//scene.add(ambientlight);
var sun = new DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.8);
sun.castShadow = true;
scene.add(sun);
sun.position.set(0, 40, 0);
//fog
//scene.fog = new Fog(0xffffff, 0, 200); 
//helpers
var gridhelper = new GridHelper(10, 10);
scene.add(gridhelper);
var axishelper = new AxesHelper(3);
scene.add(axishelper);
var directionallighthelper = new DirectionalLightHelper(sun, 10, 0xff0000);
scene.add(directionallighthelper);
//material loaders
var bildimport = new TextureLoader().load('a.jpg');
var bildimport2 = new TextureLoader().load('träd.jpg');
var textureLoader = new TextureLoader();
scene.background = textureLoader.load('a.jpg');
//objects
  //sphere
  var geometrySphere = new SphereGeometry(10, 15);
  var materialSphere = new MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xffff00f,
    flatShading: true, 
    //wireframe: true, 
  });
  var meshSphere = new Mesh(geometrySphere, materialSphere);
  scene.add(meshSphere);
  meshSphere.position.set(0,20,0);
  meshSphere.castShadow = true;
  meshSphere.receiveShadow = true;
  //cube
geometry = new BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
var alt_material = [
  new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport2}),
  new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport}),
  new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport2}),
  new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport}),
  new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport2}),
  new MeshBasicMaterial({map: bildimport}),
];
material = new MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xff0000,
    map: bildimport2,
});
mesh = new Mesh(geometry, alt_material);
mesh.position.set(0, 50, 0);
mesh.castShadow = true;
scene.add(mesh);
  //plane
var geometry2 = new PlaneGeometry(50, 50); 
var material2 = new MeshStandardMaterial({
    color: 0xfff00,
    map: bildimport,
    side: DoubleSide,  // Gör att planet färgas på båda sidor isf bara på ovansidan.
});
var mesh2 = new Mesh(geometry2, material2);
mesh2.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(mesh2);
mesh2.rotation.x = -0.5 * Math.PI;
//groups
//renderer loop 
requestAnimationFrame(render);
var i = 0;
var increase_of_i = 0.01;
function render() {
  mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
  mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
 // mesh.position.y = 100 * Math.abs(Math.sin(i));
  mesh.scale.x = 1 + Math.abs(Math.sin(2*i));
  mesh.scale.y = 1 + Math.abs(Math.sin(2*i));
  mesh.scale.z = 1 + Math.abs(Math.sin(2*i));
  i += increase_of_i;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
```

I'm tying to get the plane to receive shadow from the sphere, but somewhere on my way I do something wrong, anyone that has an idea about how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code. It should be `renderer.shadowMap.enabled` (the last `d` is missing).

Besides, you have not configured the directional light's shadow so far which might be necessary. You normally do this in a way such that the shadow camera's frustum encloses all shadow casting and receiving 3D objects. You can visually debug the frustum via `THREE.CameraHelper` like so:

```js
scene.add( new THREE.CameraHelper( sun.shadow.camera ) );
```

The frustum can be configured like so:

```js
sun.shadow.camera.top = 25;
sun.shadow.camera.bottom = - 25;
sun.shadow.camera.left = - 25;
sun.shadow.camera.right = 25;
sun.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
sun.shadow.camera.far = 100;
```

Comment: Please accept this post as an answer and upvote if it solved your issue.